# AngularJS и подключение $translateProvider

Tags: html5, angularjs, angularjs-controller, модули

Здравствуйте, братья по оружию. Столкнулся с такой проблемой: мне нужно написать форму для регистрации и логирования на сайте + сделать этот сайт на двух языках. Дело в том, что регистрацию и логирование я уже сделал, но не знаю, как подключить дополнительно в файле app.js этот самый Angular-Translator (решил делать через него, так как через Angular-getttext сложнее). Собственно, столкунлся с проблемой, так как не знаю, куда пихать $translateProvider. Вот мой код, не рабочий:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ngCookies', 'pascalprecht.translate']);
    app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $translateProvider){
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                controller: 'HomeController',
                templateUrl: 'private_page.html',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            })

            .when('/login', {
                controller: 'LoginController',
                templateUrl: 'login.html',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            })

            .when('/register', {
                controller: 'RegisterController',
                templateUrl: 'registration.html',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            })

            .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/login' });

        $translateProvider.translations('en', {
            TITLE: 'Hello',
            FOO: 'This is a paragraph.',
            BUTTON_LANG_EN: 'english',
            BUTTON_LANG_DE: 'german'
        });
        $translateProvider.translations('de', {
            TITLE: 'Hallo',
            FOO: 'Dies ist ein Paragraph.',
            BUTTON_LANG_EN: 'englisch',
            BUTTON_LANG_DE: 'deutsch'
        });
        $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');

        }
    );

    app.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope, $translate) {
        $scope.changeLanguage = function (key) {
            $translate.use(key);
        };
    });

    app.run(function ($rootScope, $location, $cookies, $http){
        // keep user logged in after page refresh
        $rootScope.globals = $cookies.getObject('globals') || {};
        if ($rootScope.globals.currentUser) {
            $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + $rootScope.globals.currentUser.authdata;
        }

        $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
            // redirect to login page if not logged in and trying to access a restricted page
            var restrictedPage = $.inArray($location.path(), ['/login', '/register']) === -1;
            var loggedIn = $rootScope.globals.currentUser;
            if (restrictedPage && !loggedIn) {
                $location.path('/login');
            }
        });
    });

})();
```

Если кто-то сталкивался или видит момент, где я затупил, и укажет мне на него, буду очень благодарен. Заранее спасибо!

P.S.Пробовал создавать новый модуль в том же app.js и в config к нему передавал функцию с параметром $translateProvider, но насколько я понял, так делать нельзя, ибо непонятно, как подключить этот модуль к html файлу дополнительно к основному модулю "app".

Comment: так ты его уже используешь

Comment: Ошибку нашел, вопрос закрывается.